# How to get a list of files in the directory os x?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm developing an application in Objective-C. The user selects a directory (using `NSOpenPanel`) and then in the application displays a list of the files in this directory. This is working without a problem.

However, if the application is open anew and without selecting a directory through `NSOpenPanel`, just want to get a list of files in the selected directory in the past startup error occurs

> NSCocoaErrorDomain Code = 257.

I suspect that if the user selects the directory manually via `NSOpenPanel`, the system somehow remembers it and give read access to this directory and getting her files (using the method `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath`), and if the user does not select via `NSOpenPanel` directory and tries to get a list of its files error is generated access.

How can that be in this case?

Comment: If your application is sandboxed, then you have to save a bookmark, not just the directory name. Please see the [documentation on security scoped bookmarks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is sandboxed and you want to have access to files/directories between runs, then you need to store a security-scoped bookmark to the directory, rather than the directory itself.

This means that you need to add the boolean property `com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope`  set to `YES` to the entitlements of the application, as well as `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` to allow file selection.

When you select the directory, you need to make a bookmark to it:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc] init];
panel.canChooseDirectories = YES;
NSInteger ret = [panel runModal];
if (ret == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
    NSURL *anUrl = [[panel URLs] lastObject];
    NSError *err;
    NSData *data = [anUrl bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
                   includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
                                    relativeToURL:nil
                                            error:&err];
    if (!data) {
        NSLog(@"%@", err);
        return NO;
    }
```

Now that you've got the bookmark, you need to persist it e.g. by doing:

```
    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setObject:data forKey:@"bookmark"];
    [def synchronize];
```

On restart of the application, you need to convert the bookmark from `NSData` back into an URL, this is done by doing:

```
BOOL stale = NO;
NSError *anError;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:data
                                       options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithSecurityScope
                                 relativeToURL:nil
                           bookmarkDataIsStale:&stale
                                         error:&anError];
if (url && !stale) {
    [anURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
    // Do something with URL
    [anURL stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
} else if (anError) {
    NSLog(@"%@", anError);
    return NO;
}
```

and if you had used the defaults persistence of the bookmark data, you would use:

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [def objectForKey:@"bookmark"];
```

to restore the bookmark data from the userdefaults.